# Traefik - Forward to external IP

Tags: docker, networking, traefik, portforwarding

I've setup my traefik in docker, and it works as intended for container discovery etc.

But I'm getting tired of having to forward port 80 to my Synology NAS in order to renew LetsEncrypt certificates.

Therefore, I want all traffic on port 80 to be forwarded to my NAS (192.168.1.4) on port 80. Based on this answer [How to get traefik to redirect to specific non-docker port from inside docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245684/how-to-get-traefik-to-redirect-to-specific-non-docker-port-from-inside-docker), I have added the following to my docker-compose:

```
labels:
  - "--providers.file=true"
  - "--providers.file.filename=/rules.toml"

volumes:
  - "/opt/docker_volumes/traefik/rules.toml:/rules.toml"
```

My rules.toml looks like this:

```
[http.routers]
  # Define a connection between requests and services
  [http.routers.nasweb]
    rule = "Host(`nas.example.com`)"
    entrypoints = ["web"]
    service = "nas"

[http.services]
  # Define how to reach an existing service on our infrastructure
  [http.services.nas.loadBalancer]
    [[http.services.nas.loadBalancer.servers]]
      url = "http://192.168.1.4:80"
```

However, I don't see any services in the traefik dashboard, nor does the certificate renew sucessfully. Can anyone spot any errors in the above?

I'm also completely open for a different solution.